# Is there an easy way to avoid duplicating commands in bash's HISTIGNORE?

Tags: bash, command-history

I'd like to ignore *all* invocations of a command in my bash history, regardless of arguments.  For example, to exclude all of `ls`, `ls -l`, and `ls SOME_DIRECTORY`, my understanding is that I'd need to do:

```bsh
HISTIGNORE='ls:ls *'
```

I can't use just `HISTIGNORE='ls*'` because that also would ignore other commands that happen to start with `ls`, which is undesirable.  However, needing to specify `ls` and `ls *` is annoying and error-prone as I add entries to `HISTIGNORE`.

Is there a pattern that I can use to match a command by itself *and* with arguments?

Comment: Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way and instead should try to generate something like `'ls:ls *:cd:cd *'` from `ls:cd`.

Comment: Depends on the usage. I would _never_ influence my original history in this way, as the relationships between the lines would be lost. Instead I would create some tools (aliases, bash functions etc.) that would present the information I need. A custom ^R created with bind (see man bash) would help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HISTIGNORE` pattern matching honors the setting of the `extglob` shell option and, with extended globbing, you can use this to match commands that start with `ls` and are followed by either a space and then anything else, or by nothing (end of the line).

```
shopt -s extglob
HISTIGNORE='ls@( *|)'
```

The `@(foo|bar)` format of bash extended globs will match exactly one of `foo` or `bar`. Here, the pattern we are giving is `ls@( *|)` so it will match `ls` at the beginning of the line and then either a space and 0 or more other following characters, or no characters at all.

Here it is in action:

```
$ shopt -s extglob 
$ export HISTIGNORE='ls@( *|)'
$ history -c
$ ls > /dev/null 
$ ls * > /dev/null
$ ls -la > /dev/null
$ ls file > /dev/null
$ lsa
-bash: lsa: command not found
$ history 
    1  lsa
    2  history
```